# How to get value from string sequence column in Oracle?

Tags: regex, oracle

I have a column which contains a pair key-value:

key1=111111|key2=222222|key3=333333|key4=444444

value is id of the column in different table. 
How can I get value '222222' if key2 exists and then use it to join with another table?

Could you provide rexeg for me? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Are you saying that you have a table with a column called KEY and a column called VALUE... ?

Comment: @BobC No, column is called "options" and it contains string like "key1=111111|key2=222222|key3=333333|key4=444444" where key is ID of  column in another table...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If this was instead in "proper form" (if instead of one value in one column you would have four rows in two columns - a table with a column for key and another for value) then it would be easy, right? And - if your column is paired to another column, an `id` of some sort, then the same column should be in the "proper form" table?

I don't ever understand how people end up having to use something like "your" existing column. But if you have no power over it, it makes the most sense to write a view (perhaps a materialized one for better performance), and use it instead of your current table. Something like:

```
create table t1 ( id number, key_val varchar2(4000) );
insert into t1 
  select 101, 'key1=111111|key2=222222|key3=333333|key4=444444' from dual union all
  select 102, 'key1=800001|key5=800002|key6=900030|key9=339900' from dual;
commit;

create view t1_view ( id, key, val ) as (
  select id, regexp_substr(key_val, '(\||^)(.*?)=', 1, level, null, 2),
             regexp_substr(key_val, '=(.*?)(\||$)', 1, level, null, 1)
  from   t1
  connect by level <= length(key_val) - length(translate(key_val, 'z=', 'z'))
         and prior id = id
         and prior sys_guid() is not null
);

select * from t1_view;

  ID KEY   VAL
---- ----- -------
 101 key1  111111
 101 key2  222222
 101 key3  333333
 101 key4  444444
 102 key1  800001
 102 key5  800002
 102 key6  900030
 102 key9  339900

8 rows selected.
```

Here `val` is still a string. If it is supposed to be a number, it is best to wrap the last `regexp_substr` within `to_number()`.

And now write all your joins to use this view instead of `t1`.

Comment: If this *really* is the design, it's horrible. It's classic case of using the product in completely the wrong way

Comment: I don't work in the industry, but I'm told this kind of bs data model is quite common, especially in old, very large organizations (hospitals, insurance companies, banks, ...) Perhaps from before RDBMS's were even invented. No reason, of course, not to fix it after so many years, but one has to deal with business managers who have no clue about any of this, and who say **no** to everything.

Comment: Unfortunately this is too common in new applications too. There is a perception that a "key-value" store is good for performance and is scalable, etc, etc, not to mention "fashionable".

Comment: Thank you very much, @mathguy!
@BobC matchguy is right. Customers say no to changes to this "design".